# Corrupted special characters using Jersey and Tomcat 7

Tags: java, jersey, tomcat7

I have a strange problem with special characters. They are corrupted but 
when I run it on localhost (Tomcat 7.0.12) is everything ok, when I deploy it at remote server (Tomcat 7.0.34) the characters are corrupted. I am realy confused.

Does anybody have similiar problem?

**localhost:**

wikicategory_Languages_of_São_Tomé_and_Príncipe

wikicategory_Subject–verb–object_languages

**remote server:**

wikicategory_Languages_of_S��o_Tom��_and_Pr��ncipe

wikicategory_Subject���verb���object_languages,

note: I have set utf-8

in endpoint:
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")

in server configuration:

server.xml

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
            redirectPort="8443"
URIEncoding="utf-8"
maxPostSize="0"
maxHttpHeaderSize="131072" />
```

Comment: Where are those special characters contained?

Comment: Perhaps your code uses "default platform encoding" to read strings, which may be different between the two servers.  Where are those characters coming from?  Is it the body of an HTTP request?

Comment: It is in body of http repsponse (in json object). You could see it exactly here: http://ir.lmcloud.vse.cz/irapi/media-server/?q=media_type%3Awebpage&thd=yes&row=1

Comment: Yes, but where does it come from?  How did the server make this page?

Comment: Yes, sorry :) well the proces is this:

Comment: Hey...thanks for your guideing, thanks to you I go throught the whole process and found where I had bug, it was in converting Inpustream to String, where I have to also declare encoding new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8")); instead of new InputStreamReader(is); ... but the different behaviour on servers was really confusing ...

Comment: OK, I'm not sure whether I was really any help; but I'm happy that you got it to work.